# How to specify the size of a Rubik’s cube?

Tags: english-to-german, preposition

How can I say that I’ve solved an *N×N×N* Rubik’s cube in German?

In English, you’d say e.g. *four by four by four.* What’s the equivalent preposition in German?

> Ich habe einen 2×2×2-Zauberwürfel gelöst.

Comment: Welcome to German Language SE. I took the liberty to remove your second question as it is not tied to the first one. You may ask it separately though, considering our [guidelines for translation questions](http://meta.german.stackexchange.com/q/628/2594).

Comment: Thanks for the improvement. I already got the answer to my second question so that's not a problem.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

To define a matrix in German you would say *zwei mal zwei*, and *lösen* (to solve) would be the right verb.

> Ich habe einen zwei-mal-zwei-mal-zwei-Zauberwürfel [also in German sometimes Rubik’s Cube] gelöst.

Comment: Oft auch mit der Variante "kreuz" statt "mal". Also ein "Zwei-kreuz-zwei-kreuz-zwei-Zauberwürfel". Ich nutze auch persönlich "Zwei-kreuz-zwei-Zauberwürfel" und "Zweier-Zauberwürfel".

Comment: Die Kreuz-Variante habe ich noch nie gehört

Comment: _-Kreuz-_ habe ich auch noch nie gehört. Zweier- oder Dreier-Würfel würde ich auch benutzen, stimmt.

Comment: Die *-Kreuz-* Variante ist recht beliebt unter Mathematikern (die vor allem im ersten Semester plötzlich verrückt nach den Würfeln sind).

Comment: Noch etwas: Ich persönlich würde "four" eher mit "vier" übersetzen. Einigen wir uns auf "drei" als Kompromiss?

Answer (score 5):

Zumindest in Süddeutschland ist es auch üblich, die Dimensionen bei Würfeln nicht einzeln zu benennen, also einfach zu sagen:

> Ich habe einen 2er-Zauberwürfel gelöst.